# Nginx with Njs - error on startup

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have nginx/1.14.0 installed on an Ubuntu, 16.04 LTS EC2 instance. I cloned njs (http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs_about.html) using `hg clone http://hg.nginx.org/njs`.

I configured the nginx source to add the njs module like so, `./configure --add-module=/home/ubuntu/njs/nginx`, and installed nginx.

I am using njs for scripting some handlers to process incoming requests.

However, when starting up nginx the following error is displayed:

> nginx: [emerg] failed to create JS VM in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:34

The relevant part of my nginx.conf:

```
http {
    js_include routeHandler.js; # <-- this is line 34 from the error
    js_set     $path path;

    server {
        listen 80;

        access_log logs/access.log main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass $path$request_uri;
        }

    }
}
```

The routeHandler.js file is located in the same directory as my nginx.conf: `/usr/local/nginx/conf`

Nginx runs fine without the njs script included. Am I missing something? I have installed all dependencies for Nginx.

Comment: In case any one is still looking for answers, please use nginx:nginx:1.19 onwards since the njs was made native module. It should just like that work as is. Do let me know if you want a working example, I will upload to github.